# Aggregate on the max element of a join table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables message, message user and user.

I want to extract a list of conversation where the user received the last message in each ones, and i want to access the data of this message as well.
The order of the list of conversation should be the ones containing the last messages received first.
(conversation is just an id on message.conversation)

I get something almost working like this:

```
SELECT mu.*
     , m.id message_id
     , m.conversation message_conversation
     , m.from message_from
     , m.text message_text
     , m.date_created message_date_created
     , user1.type user1_type
     , user1.name user1_name
     , user1.email user1_email
     , user1.avatar_blob_key user1_avatar_blob_key 
  FROM message_user mu
  LEFT 
  JOIN message m
    ON m.id = mu.message 
  LEFT 
  JOIN user user1 
    ON user1.id = m.from 
 WHERE mu.to = THE_USER_ID 
 GROUP  
    BY m.conversation 
 ORDER 
    BY mu.message DESC;
```

But this query doesn't get the last message received but the first one in each conversation instead :/

It looks like this part `ORDER BY message_user.message DESC` is not used by the query.

Comment: This is a standard GROUPWISE MAX question. Answered many, many times before.

Comment: I guess so, but i don't know what is wrong in my query... Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY clause is always inappropriate.

Comment: The aggregation should be MAX(message.id) but I try to include this but then i will get only one record returned.

Comment: How is it that `message.id` is *guaranteed* to always be ever increasing? Relying on auto_increment, IMHO, isn't safe because it doesn't protect against the crazy DBA scenario where someone inserts specific values into the table.

Comment: True Thomas we can go with message.date_created actually, good point

Comment: Incidentally, as I never tire of saying, the 'uncorrelated subquery' solution to this problem, as documented in the manual (and nearly as described by Mihai below), is nearly always faster than other methods.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Strawberry I didn't know, I am not at all an expert went it comes to SQL, that's why I am asking for help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to reiterate your request, the message rows that should be returned should be ones where the last message in the given conversation is one *to* the user in question. Assuming that is correct, you could try something like the following:

```
Select MU.*
     , M.id As message_id
     , M.conversation As message_conversation
     , M.from As message_from
     , M.text As message_text
     , M.date_created As message_date_created
     , FromUser.type As user1_type
     , FromUser.name As user1_name
     , FromUser.email As user1_email
     , FromUser.avatar_blob_key As user1_avatar_blob_key 
From message_user As MU
    Left Join message As M
        On M.id = MU.message
            And M.date_created =    (
                                    Select Max( M1.date_created )
                                    From message As M1
                                    Where M1.conversation = M.conversation
                                    )
    Left Join user As FromUser
        On FromUser.id = M.from
Where MU.to = <some user id>
Group By M.conversation
Order By MU.message Desc;
```

Comment: Hi Thomas yes it is correct, just one problem in your query And M.to = MU.to : message.to doesn't exist only message.from

Comment: message_user and message are linked by the message id: message.id = message_user.message only

Comment: @JeromeAnsia - Some actual schema would be useful here. I removed the filter on `M.to = MU.to` and I do not believe it will materially change the result of the query.

Comment: Hey Thomas, I think I got your query almost working, I just have a weird empty row on the result set, let me look if i can solve this and get back to you and post a full schema if i don't find the solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok I added "AND M.id != 0" in the where close (last one) and I got it working, I don't really get why I got this but... It's working ;) Thanks again for your help!!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT mu.*
     , message.id message_id
     , message.conversation message_conversation
     , message.from message_from
     , message.text message_text
     , message.date_created message_date_created
     , user1.type user1_type
     , user1.name user1_name
     , user1.email user1_email
     , user1.avatar_blob_key user1_avatar_blob_key 
  FROM message_user mu
  LEFT 
  JOIN (select max(id) id,`from`
       from message
       group by `from`)max
    ON max.id = mu.message 
  LEFT 
  JOIN user user1 
    ON user1.id = message.from 
 WHERE mu.to = THE_USER_ID 
 GROUP  
    BY message.conversation 
 ORDER 
    BY mu.message DESC;
```

Comment: Just a dizzy first attempt, a fiddle would help me .

Comment: Thanks Mihai it breaks at the 2nd line, m.id is an unknown column